# How to get acknowledgement back from put method on IBM MQ?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

This is the sample code i am using, however, i don't know how to get a response back from put or access queue, that the message is sent.

```
 mqQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue("Queue Name", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT |
 MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED |       MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE); 
 mqQueue.Put(mqMsg, mqPutMsgOpts);
```

PUT method is a void return type, if it would have been bool for example, based on the return value - true/false, i can confirm, message was sent to the queue, that is what my question, how do i get back an acknowledgement,so that message is sent to the queue.

Any inputs will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating as per comments clarifying the question:

Enclose your `PUT` in a try block and catch the `MQException`.  If no `MQException` was thrown, then the `PUT` worked and you got back RC=0.  For example, this is from the sample `PUT` program:

```
    void PutMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            // mq properties
            properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);

            // display all details
            Console.WriteLine("MQ Parameters");
            Console.WriteLine("1) queueName = " + queueName);
            Console.WriteLine("2) host = " + hostName);
            Console.WriteLine("3) port = " + port);
            Console.WriteLine("4) channel = " + channelName);
            Console.WriteLine("5) numberOfMsgs = " + numberOfMsgs);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // create connection
            Console.Write("Connecting to queue manager.. ");
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
            Console.WriteLine("done");

            // accessing queue
            Console.Write("Accessing queue " + queueName + ".. ");
            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            Console.WriteLine("done");

            // creating a message object
            message = new MQMessage();
            message.WriteString(messageString);

            // putting messages continuously
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMsgs; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Message " + i + " <" + messageString + ">.. ");
                queue.Put(message);
                Console.WriteLine("put");
            }

            // closing queue
            Console.Write("Closing queue.. ");
            queue.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("done");

            // disconnecting queue manager
            Console.Write("Disconnecting queue manager.. ");
            queueManager.Disconnect();
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }

        catch (MQException mqe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("MQException caught: {0} - {1}", mqe.ReasonCode, mqe.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(mqe.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

As noted, this is from the sample code and a real program intended for Production would probably have more granular exception handling.  That said, the API call will either succeed or throw an `MQException`.  The exact behavior depends on your options.  For example, if you request message conversion on a `GET` it's possible to get a conversion error whereas the exact same message retrieved as a binary payload would succeed.

---

Previous response:

I'm not sure I understand the question, but what I *think* you are asking is how to design a request/reply program using WebSphere MQ and that's how I'll respond.  However, if by "response" you actually meant the reason and return code from the `PUT`, please clarify the question and I'll update my answer.

The usual pattern for request/response is that the requesting program first opens the reply-to queue.  If the name of the queue that is opened is a model queue, the queue manager creates a dynamic queue and returns a handle to that.  Otherwise, the queue must be a pre-existing local queue.

Once the application has a handle on the reply-to queue, it opens the request queue and creates a new request message.  The name of the local reply-to queue is used to initialize the `replyToQueue` field of the request message.  The local queue manager name is automatically filled in for the message's `replyToQMgr` field.  The app then puts the message and waits on the reply in the reply-to queue.

If there are several app instances listening on the same reply-to queue, they usually specify a correlation ID for the specific message they want.  The usual design is that the server that reads the request message puts the `MQMD.MsgID` into the `MQMD.CorrelID` field of the reply message however sometimes it transfers the incoming message ID to the outbound message ID.

Be sure to `COMMIT` the `PUT` before issuing the `GET` or else you will *never* get a reply.

There's more on this in the Infocenter topic [*Design of the Request sample program*](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fg17540_.htm) and you can find the sample programs at `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\dotnet` in a default Windows WMQ client installation.  I would encourage you to familiarize yourself with the samples and reuse some of the code from there.  If you didn't actually download and install the full client, pick up a copy free at [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75).  Then when you install it, be sure to select the option to install the SDK and sample code.

Comment: Thanks. PUT method is a void return type, if it would have been bool for example, based on the return value - true/false, i can confirm, message was sent to the queue, that is what my question, how do i get back an acknowledgement,so that message is sent to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i get back an acknowledgement,so that message is sent to the
>   queue

If Put method does NOT throw an exception then THAT is your acknowledgement that MQ has put the message to the queue.